# What metric captures why my OSX machine is so slow during XCode indexing

Tags: osx-lion

My entire machine OSX Lion machine slows down while XCode 4.4 is indexing. The CPU is less than 10% busy, I've got over 500 MB free memory, plenty of disk space, disk IO rate is not high, network activity is not high. Indexing just a few files can take minutes and builds are extremely slow. While this is going on, even loading a new web page in Chrome can be slow.

Knowing how to fix it would be great, but more fundamentally how can I measure what is actually going slowly? What metrics should I be looking at? Nothing in Activity Monitor, iostat, top, or sar betray anything about what's going on to me. Even getting a man page is interminable.

Comment: To blindly fix this I've tried deleting "DerivedData", running fsck, disabling "on access scan" in McAfee, and installing Mountain Lion.

Comment: Oddly, the machine seems happier now. After installing Mountain Lion an error was reported on TimeMachine and I had to select a new volume on my USB TimeMachine drive. Perhaps that was the issue.

Comment: Additionally, I had a file that had been deleted from the file system but not from subversion, and it seem to give Xcode fits. Doing a svn delete seemed to help.